# GDB seems to be trying to debug a python file even though launch.json tells it to debug C++

Tags: c++, gdb

In VSCode, when I try to debug a C++ binary with GDB, it gives the following error:

```
Unable to start debugging. Unable to establish a connection to GDB. The following message was written to stderr:

Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
 PYTHONHOME = (not set)
 PYTHONPATH = (not set)
 program name = '/usr/bin/python'
 isolated = 0
 environment = 1
 user site = 1
 safe_path = 0
 import site = 1
 is in build tree = 0
 stdlib dir = '/usr/lib/python3.11'
 sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python'
 sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
 sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
 sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
 sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python'
 sys.prefix = '/usr'
 sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
 sys.path = [
  '/usr/lib/python311.zip',
  '/usr/lib/python3.11',
  '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
 ]
Python Exception <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>: No module named 'encodings'
Python not initialized

See Output Window for details
```

I could not find the output window the error was talking about.

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "logging": {"engineLogging" : true},
      "setupCommands": [
          {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          },
          {
              "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
              "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
              "ignoreFailures": true
          }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

I really have no idea what to do, the only thing I could think of was restarting my computer, which did not fix the issue. Does anyone have any idea what problem I am encountering? Thanks!

Comment: pretty printing is done in GDB using a Python interpreter.

Comment: It may be a typical msys problem - msys programs need to be run in msys terminal, otherwise you have to manually set up paths that are set by default in that terminal. Your Python interpreter couldn't find a standard library module, so that seems quite possible.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Do you know what paths/how would I set up the paths in VSCode?

Comment: No, sorry. You can try to run `gdb` in the msys terminal - if it can launch and run your program, that's it (and it should be possible to search the internet on what the actual solution would be). Or maybe someone can answer then.

Comment: It gives the exact same error when I try to use gdb in the msys terminal

Comment: I can't help directly but you're doing something a little unusual -- most people on windows would be installing Microsoft compiler, which is free for home use. I.e. Microsoft Visual Studio Installer, a.k.a. Build Tools for Visual Studio, from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads -- recommend get MSVC, Windows SDK, C++ CMake tools for Windows, Testing tools core features, C++ AddressSanitizer, and C++ Clang Tools. I use this on Windows and on linux I use gcc or clang, with gdb, and it all works fine.